# Android: unable to move a project

Tags: android

I am trying to move a project. I have clicked `move`, set the path to the desired location, and then imported the project.

When I try to run the app I get an error:

```
Installation failed with message Invalid File: /home/<my_path>/slices/slice_0.apk.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

I clicked "Yes", and I keep getting the same error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps, delete your emulator, and make a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean the project, after that rebuild it.

[image]

If it still does not work, uncheck instant run

[image]